# Rails self referential has_many through: is not adding the right record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Been wrecking my brain all day for this. I created a has_many through relationships for a `pool_tournament_match` so each match can have many other matches. I created a table called 
`pool_tournament_match_relationships`.

`create_table :pool_tournament_match_relationships do |t|
   t.belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'PoolTournamentMatch', index: true
   t.timestamps
end`

## pool_tournament_match.rb

`has_many :pool_tournament_match_relationships,
    class_name: 'PoolTournamentMatchRelationship',
    foreign_key: :parent_id
has_many :parents, through: :pool_tournament_match_relationships`

So, I should be able to do something like `match.pool_tournament_match_relationships.create(parent: anotherMatch)`

However, when I do this, the record added to the relationships table is actually that of `match` and not `anotherMatch`. So, for example if match id is 1 and anotherMatch id is 2. 1 will be entered into the relationships table.

Here is the output from the console:

`m.pool_tournament_match_relationships.create(parent: m2)`

`INSERT INTO "pool_tournament_match_relationships" ("parent_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["parent_id", 1], ["created_at", 2016-11-08 21:51:29 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-11-08 21:51:29 UTC]]`

Notice that `parent_id` entered is 1 which is the id of m instead of m2.

`irb(main):012:0> m.id
=> 1
irb(main):013:0> m2.id
=> 5`

I appreciate your help!

EDIT: Add the schema for the relationships table:

  `create_table "pool_tournament_match_relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["parent_id"], name: "index_pool_tournament_match_relationships_on_parent_id", using: :btree
  end`

Comment: do you have only one foreign key in `pool_tournament_match_relationships` table?

Comment: I added the schema. Looks like there is only one integer for parent_id.

Comment: Your has-many-through relationship will not work unless you have both a `parent_id` field and a `pool_tournament_match_id` field. See the example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With has-many-through relationships, you shouldn't have to mess with creating the records for the relationship table or assigning attributes to them. Just use basic operators on the operative classes and let Rails figure out the relationships for you.

The names of your classes are long and I'm not quite straight in my head how they work, so I'll illustrate with some from one of my projects.

```
# app/models/event.rb

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :aid_stations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :splits, through: :aid_stations
...
end

# app/models/split.rb

class Split < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :aid_stations, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :events, through: :aid_stations
...
end

# app/models/aid_station.rb

class AidStation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :split
...
end

# app/controllers/events_controller.rb

class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_event
  ...

  def associate_split
    @event.splits << Split.find(params[:split_id])
    redirect_to splits_event_path(id: @event.id)
  end

  def remove_split
    @event.splits.delete(params[:split_id])
    redirect_to splits_event_path(@event)
  end

  private

  def set_event
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Note that `associate_split` creates an aid_station record and `remove_split` destroys one, but there is no mention of any aid_stations in the methods. Rails takes care of that behind the scenes.

This would work equally well in the splits_controller if I had chosen to put the `associate` and `remove` methods there.

EDIT: Here's the relevant portion of the schema for `aid_stations`:

```
  create_table "aid_stations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.integer  "split_id"
    ...
  end
```

Comment: I do have a couple of has_many through associations and they work for me. This one doesn't work because I"m assuming it's a self referential. I'm not connection two entities via a join table. I'm connecting the same entity via a join table and it got confused. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: In that case, I think you need to alias the operative class so it can reference itself. I'm not sure how it can work without two foreign key fields in the reference table. How else will the relationship exist?

Comment: You are right. I'm weak with RDMS and not sure how rails association really works on that level. I followed this a railscast tutorial and it works. Thanks!